# Undefinded Variable using PHP

Tags: php

I am getting the following

```
Notice: Undefined variable: array(1,2) in C:\[PATH]\index.php on line 21
```

But the 'array' still operates correctly.

I have defined the variable from a combination of letters and results from a SQL query.

The code is:

```
 <?php 

    $pageId = '1';

    require_once('includes/dbConnect-SQL.php');

    if($dbSuccess) {
                    $qry = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(userId) userId
                    FROM security WHERE pageId = '$pageId'";

                    $result = mysql_query($qry);               

                    }

                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_BOTH)) {

                    $userArray = $row['userId'];

                    $rul = 'array(' . $userArray . ')'; } 

    $requiredUserLevel = $$rul;
    $defaultDir =  'secure/';
    include($defaultDir . "secure.php");

?>
```

I have the results of the table echo'ing as 1,2,3 etc which is what I want, but I need the `$requiredUserLevel` to actually look like this:

```
$requiredUserLevel = array(1,2,3);
```

With the group_concat used as the numbers in the array brackets.

Any help is appreciated, I have no idea what I am doing.

Comment: "I have no idea what I am doing" - at all?! This is sad. Read some stuff, bro.

Comment: What is the purpose of this line $rul = 'array(' . $userArray . ')'; directly store values in an array and then use any where

Comment: If you are actually trying to get a real array, try exploding: `$requiredUserLevel = explode(",",$userArray);` From what I can tell the `$userArray` should be comma separated string???

Comment: What is the code on your index.php file line number 21

Answer (score 1):

`$rul` will be a string. When `$rul = 'array(1,2,3)';` and you are using it like `$$rul` it will look for a variable named `array(1,2,3)`.

Simply do this. -

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_BOTH)) {
    $requiredUserLevel = explode(',' , $row['userId']);
}
```

And if it is fetching a single row then no need of that loop also.

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
$requiredUserLevel = $$rul;
```

to this:

```
$requiredUserLevel = $rul;
```

Now, value of `$rul` became a variable, that's why you are getting error from PHP.

Answer (score -1):

It is not error, it's `notice`! If you don't want get such notices, add to your php.ini this line:

> `error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE`

Best lucks!

Comment: This is like saying instead of flushing your toilet after use just close the lid.

Comment: Marty, I didn't mean such that you had said. I only showed the way. there is no anything about `notice` up there, In that case, it is not using toilet, it is about that your water mixer doesn't work correctly